what happens with kvm-support after 18.04?
I have now tried live 18.04 desktop, installed server 22.04 and 24.04 and tried live 24.04 desktop.
Of those 4 only the live 18.04 was giving support for kvm on my Intel Xeon E-2146G cpu.
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
gives 12 when bootet 18.04, but zero on all the others.
No changes in bios between the attempts and all settings are 'on' in my BIOS.
What needs to be done in order to launch LXC-container with -vm flag ?

I really wonder why 18.4 gave 12 in that response, I did a search in BIOS for VMX, and found one feature that was actually turned off, When I turned it on, 24.04 now respondes with 24, and it seems virtualization actually works as it should.

Look for kvm-intel.nested=0 in grub and remove it. Install intel-microcode and try these commands: "modprobe kvm" and "modprobe kvm-intel". Then go for "dmesg | grep -i kvm" and "dmesg | grep -i vmx". Can you post these results?

ensure all settings related to VT and VMX is not only available but also turned on, as resetting to default-settings may very well turn those off...
kvm_intel: VMX not enabled (by BIOS) in MSR_IA32_FEAT_CTL on CPU 10

was the line making me recheck BIOS even once more for VMX-attribute
